# Array arrangement in table

Tags: php, arrays

I need help, am having problem with **Array results.**

The code that i'm using:

```
   $presents = json_decode(fBGetDataStore('presents'), true);
```

and to print the result:

```
       <?= print_r($presents) ?>
```

shows this **result:**

```
  Array ( [0] => Array ( [sender] => 100009016810227 [itemCode] => 0f8g [itemContext] => normal [extraData] => ) 
          [1] => Array ( [sender] => 100009016810227 [itemCode] => 0fcm [itemContext] => normal [extraData] => )
```

But I **want result:**

```
[1] Sender ID: 100009016810227 and Item Code is 0f8g
[2] Sender ID: 100009016810227 and Item Code is 0fcm
```

Comment: Why do you want to the outputted keys to start at 1?

Comment: that is number count ... or its not necessary to count results .. 
this format is also acceptable    
       
      `Sender ID: 100009016810227 and Item Code is 0f8g`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i did as you said @FatAdama

**Coding :**

`foreach ($presents as $key=>$value) {
     echo 'Sender ID: '.$value['sender'].' and Item Code is '.$value['itemCode'].'<br>';
   }`

and i get my desire results ^_^ :

`Sender ID: 100009016810227 and Item Code is 0f8g
Sender ID: 100009016810227 and Item Code is 0fcm`

Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

You could just simply iterate through with a foreach and build the desired output into an output array, like this

```
foreach ($presents as $key=>$value) {
     $newKey = $key + 1;
     $output[$newKey] = "Sender ID: {$value['sender']} and Item Code is {$value['itemCode']}";
}
```

Where `$output` should be an array formatted to your specifications.

Comment: i don't where i'm doing mistake (i'm a new php learner). Noting showing in results .

Comment: Maybe if you tried to echo the output instead of assigning it to a new array? Iterating through arrays can be tricky at first.